# An alternative word for "lest"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Reading a book from 1995, I encountered the word *lest* in the proof of a theorem. I had not seen it in about twenty years of reading and working on mathematical contexts.  Is this word used nowadays? Babylon suggested to use "against the possibility" instead of it but I found it very easy and beautiful. Did this online software suggest me correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a conjunction mostly used in formal documents. The word originally comes from old English and means to *prevent something undesirable from happening* and *in case*.

> She tiptoed *lest* her mother should hear her. Meaning *in order to prevent* here.
>
> She worried *lest* she should be late. Meaning *in case* here.

A good alternative is *in order to prevent* and *in case* both used in different contexts.

*Examples source Wordweb.*

Comment: Thank you all for the nice answers. Thank you Noah for the examples. I got the point of them completely. :)

Answer (score 3):

One good alternative is to use **so as not to**

> Do not play with matches lest you (should) burn.
>
> Do not play with matches **so as not to** burn.

Answer (score 2):

The normal meaning of 'lest' is roughly "so that [it] does not happen", i.e. you do some precaution **lest** a consequence should happen.

I would say that its use is fairly literary, which may be why you did not encounter it before.

Answer (score 2):

The word *lest* means "for fear that" or "so (not) that", and is actually an old contraction of a phrase which ended in "that". You can, for example, replace "*lest* we forget" with "*for fear that* we forget" or "*so that* we forget *not*" or "*so that* we *[do] not* forget".

Answer (score 1):

"Lest" is a Conjunction and used in a formal register. Plus the fact that it employs the Subjunctive Mood makes it belong to an even smaller group.

> Ex. She walked swiftly lest she **be** noticed.

You could substitute to this word: "to avoid (the risk of)" or, in other situations, "in case."

Answer (score -2):

Long ago, I happen to encounter the phrase "for fear that," as the meaning of or in exchange for the word "lest." Ex. I feel pressured of being chosen for this position lest I may fall short of the expectations.

Comment: How does this add anything to MetaEd’s answer from over 5 years ago?